# Debugging exceptions in python with VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

Let's say I am running some python code and an exception is thrown, and the traceback tells me which line in my code caused the issue.  I can then try to debug by placing a breakpoint at that line.  This will stop execution the first (and every subsequent) time that line of code is run.  However, it is often the case that the line is run many times, and only throws an exception in one particular instance.  Is there an easy way to set up a break point at this line to only break if an exception occurs there?

I find myself often using the following approach, but it is a bit cumbersome to have to write each time:

Original:

```
[OTHER CODE]

[LINE OF CODE DOING CAUSING PROBLEM]

[OTHER CODE]
```

Modified:

```
[OTHER CODE]

try:
  [LINE OF CODE DOING CAUSING PROBLEM]
except:
  print("problem!")  # << place break point here

[OTHER CODE]
```

Is there a cleaner/more direct way to get this behavior?

Comment: Instead of choosing "Run Python File" to run the code, you can choose "Debug Python File" and it will stop on exception.

Comment: Have you tried to use debugging mode? You could read [document about VSCode Python Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - I am using debugging mode, and placing a breakpoint to catch what happens at a particular line that is throwing an error.  However, the issue that it doesn't throw an error the first time that line runs, it throws it the (eg) 67'th time because of some particular feature of the variables at that point in the execution.  So I only want the breakpoint to catch when in the situation where an error is being thrown.  The extra try/except code I added above (with an indicated VS Code breakpoint as well) is to acheive this, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing in VS code then you can simply put breakpoint at any line and debug the code using option Debug Python File.

As you have not provided much details and hence I have considered simple example using which we can identify which value/index is having the error. May be you can try something similar.
Code:

```
input_data = [1,2,3,0,4]
try:
    for i in input_data:
        #print("Output is", 10/i)
        a = 10 / i
except Exception as e:
    print("Error value is", i) 
    print("Error index number", input_data.index(i))
```

This gives me output as

Error value is 0
Error index number 3

Hope this helps

Comment: So I was hoping there was a way to do this using VS Code itself, ie, without having to change the code (eg, by adding try/except clauses, as you have here, and I had in my example approach above).  For one thing, it is repetitive to have to keep writing this, and there are some cases where changing code causes additional problems - eg, if you are calling the code from a jupyter notebook and don't want to restart (i know there are options to reload modules, but that is yet another step and sometimes behaves unreliably).  It seems like this is be a common workflow that should be supported.